# How to delete page of AuiNotebook?

Tags: wxpython

I created frame with AuiNotebook and redefine EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CLOSE event where DeletePage is called:

```
def OnAuiNotebookPageClose( self, event ):
    auinotebook = event.GetEventObject()
    page_idx = event.GetSelection()
    auinotebook.DeletePage(page_idx)
```

On click the "X" button on the page the event is invoked, but DeletePage always returned False, page was not removed... What is wrong in my code?

Please see my code below.

```
import wx
import wx.xrc
import wx.aui

class Frame1 ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHints( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_auinotebook1 = wx.aui.AuiNotebook( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.aui.AUI_NB_DEFAULT_STYLE )
        self.m_panel2 = wx.Panel( self.m_auinotebook1, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_auinotebook1.AddPage( self.m_panel2, u"page1", True, wx.NullBitmap )
        self.m_panel3 = wx.Panel( self.m_auinotebook1, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_auinotebook1.AddPage( self.m_panel3, u"page2", False, wx.NullBitmap )
        self.m_panel4 = wx.Panel( self.m_auinotebook1, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_auinotebook1.AddPage( self.m_panel4, u"page3", False, wx.NullBitmap )

        bSizer1.Add( self.m_auinotebook1, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer1 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.m_auinotebook1.Bind( wx.aui.EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CLOSE, self.OnAuiNotebookPageClose )

    def OnAuiNotebookPageClose( self, event ):
        auinotebook = event.GetEventObject()
        page_idx = event.GetSelection()
        auinotebook.DeletePage(page_idx)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Frame1(None)
    frame.CenterOnScreen()
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the event to `EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CLOSED` Not `EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CLOSE`
Use `RemovePage` then `DeletePage`
i.e.:

```
    self.m_auinotebook1.Bind( wx.aui.EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CLOSED, self.OnAuiNotebookPageClose )

def OnAuiNotebookPageClose( self, event ):
    auinotebook = event.GetEventObject()
    page_idx = event.GetSelection()
    auinotebook.RemovePage(page_idx)
    auinotebook.DeletePage(page_idx)
```