# WxPython Show and Hide auinotebook when close tab or notebook

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

hello I had created a design with wxformbuilder and consists of two tabs of **wx.auinotebook** and a menubar with the option to open the tab that was closed.

```
import wx
import wx.aui

wx.ID_ShPn1 = 1000

class MyFrame1 ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHints( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        self.m_menubar1 = wx.MenuBar( 0 )
        self.m_menu5 = wx.Menu()
        self.m_menu2 = wx.Menu()
        self.m_menuItem1 = wx.MenuItem( self.m_menu2, wx.ID_ShPn1, u"panel1", wx.EmptyString, wx.ITEM_NORMAL )
        self.m_menu2.Append( self.m_menuItem1 )

        self.m_menu5.AppendSubMenu( self.m_menu2, u"Show" )

        self.m_menubar1.Append( self.m_menu5, u"Inicio" )

        self.SetMenuBar( self.m_menubar1 )

        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_splitter1 = wx.SplitterWindow( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.SP_3D )
        self.m_splitter1.Bind( wx.EVT_IDLE, self.m_splitter1OnIdle )

        self.m_panel1 = wx.Panel( self.m_splitter1, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        bSizer2 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_auinotebook1 = wx.aui.AuiNotebook( self.m_panel1, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.aui.AUI_NB_DEFAULT_STYLE|wx.aui.AUI_NB_MIDDLE_CLICK_CLOSE )
        self.m_auinotebook1.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_HIGHLIGHT ) )

        self.m_panel2 = wx.Panel( self.m_auinotebook1, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_panel2.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_GRAYTEXT ) )

        self.m_auinotebook1.AddPage( self.m_panel2, u"a page", True, wx.NullBitmap )
        self.m_panel4 = wx.Panel( self.m_auinotebook1, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_auinotebook1.AddPage( self.m_panel4, u"panel 1", False, wx.NullBitmap )

        bSizer2.Add( self.m_auinotebook1, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.m_panel1.SetSizer( bSizer2 )
        self.m_panel1.Layout()
        bSizer2.Fit( self.m_panel1 )
        self.m_splitter1.Initialize( self.m_panel1 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_splitter1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer1 )
        self.Layout()
        self.m_statusBar1 = self.CreateStatusBar( 1, wx.STB_SIZEGRIP, wx.ID_ANY )

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.Bind( wx.EVT_MENU, self.Show_panel, id = self.m_menuItem1.GetId() )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass

    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class

    def Show_panel( self, event ):
        event.Skip() 

    def m_splitter1OnIdle( self, event ):
        self.m_splitter1.SetSashPosition( 0 )
        self.m_splitter1.Unbind( wx.EVT_IDLE )

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = wx.App(False)
        frame = MyFrame1(None)
        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
```

in this code I want to make it show the tab that I had closed.

```
    def Show_panel( self, event ):
        event.Skip()
```

What code can I use so that **when I close a tabs or notebook, I can open again** from this action.

Comment: Hello. I see you're still a relatively new user to StackOverflow. Just so you know, people here usually like to see that users have made at least some effort to solve the problem themselves before asking a question. In the future, please make sure to include what steps you've already taken to try and find a solution.

Comment: Hello **acattle** Sorry, I'll try my future questions, thank you very much for letting me know

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start by looking at [this question about how to delete AuiNotebook pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51875455/how-to-delete-page-of-auinotebook).

However, there is one big difference between that question and yours: you want to be able to re-add the page after it's closed. If you look at that solution, you can see that they call both [`AuiNotebook.RemovePage()`](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.aui.AuiNotebook.html?highlight=auinotebook#wx.aui.AuiNotebook.RemovePage) and [`AuiNotebook.DeletePage()`](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.aui.AuiNotebook.html?highlight=auinotebook#wx.aui.AuiNotebook.DeletePage). Looking at the documentation for both functions, it should become obvious that while you do want to remove the page, you do not want to delete it. Thus, as long as you don't call `DeletePage()` you should easily be able to re-add your page at a later time using `AddPage()`

Comment: Yes I use it `self.m_auinotebook1.Bind( wx.aui.EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CLOSED, self.OnAuiNotebookPageClose )`

Comment: what would be the difference when using `DeletePage()` of `RemovePage`?

Comment: 1) Why didn't you include `self.OnAuiNotebookPageClose()` in your question? It's the most relevant part! 2) Read the links I provided. `RemovePage()` removes the page without deleting it. `DeletePage()` deletes it. If you delete it it is gone and you can't open it again. As long as you don't delete it, you should be able to reopen it.